# Lync Ucwa bypass Lync client

Tags: lync, ucwa

I'm writing a Windows Form app that will include an embedded Lync client. I am using the Lync UCWA api and I want to be able to send messages between 2 instances of the running Windows Form app. When I try to send a message from the Windows Form app, the native Lync client always pops up to receive it. I can't figure out how to bypass the native Lync client and force the message to appear in the Windows Form app instead.

I've read about running Lync in UISuppressed mode, but I don't want to do this because users might need to use it (this is an internal application).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot really control or prevent that. Both standard Lync client, and your UCWA app, are active registered (user) endpoint for that user.
This is called in Lync terminology MPOP: Multiple point of presence.
This is same as the situation where, for instance, you have Lync signed-in for the same user on two different machines, or on a PC and a phone.
Conversation invitation ("toast") is automatically created with the first message sent to a user, which initiates the conversation, is delivered to all endpoint (endpoint's local presence status may influence).
It's dependent then on the different clients, how this is handled, and following message in the conversation will be delivered only to the endpoint which has accepted the conversation.

So, I don't think you have a way to prevent the standard client(s) to show a toast when a conversation is starting.

Hopefully, this article can provide you more information and examples about MPOP and IM: 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/11/archive/2014/01/31/lync-2013-explained-instant-message-delivery-in-spop-amp-mpop-scenarios.aspx

Answer (score -1):

If you know the [GRUU](http://blog.greenl.ee/2011/11/16/gruu/) of the endpoint (which you probably do, because it's your own application), you can send a message specifically to that uri, rather than just a user's "main" sip uri.

Basically every endpoint has a specific GRUU (a unique address), and sending messages to it means it specifically goes there rather than notify every active endpoint a user has. When you have a `LocalEndpoint` instance, the GRUU can be found on the [`EndpointUri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.localendpoint.endpointuri%28v=office.13%29.aspx) property.

Comment: that's maybe for UCMA and not for UCWA

Comment: You should still be able to target a specific endpoint, even in MPOP situations. It is after all the reason the GRUU exists: to deal with a single sip address having multiple endpoints. Assuming UCWA allows you to use a GRUU and does not force just a simple sip address, this should just work.